# Create/Select file from select field

Tags: entities, 6, files

I have a content type **video**. It has some fileds for file meta data and a file upload field. Upload and display works fine.

Now I want to add a second video file to this content type. This file can either be uploaded or selected from a select field.

So you can select a previously uploaded file or add a new one. The select box should show all files that where added for any post with content type video.

Any ideas how to do this? I am using drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileField Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module you are looking for, it is an extension to the FileField module. The FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means, including:

> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

[image]